# Which will perform better a PHP/MySQL photo gallery or ASP.NET/C# photo gallery?

Tags: performance

Imagine that we have PHP/MySQL photo gallery on Linux VPS with ***4 GB*** Ram and 2 CPUs. On the other side we have ASP.NET/C#/SQL Server photo gallery with Windows 2008 VPS  and **2 GB** Ram and 2 CPUs.

Assuming they have been coded by the same programmer to perform the same functionality. Which will perform better in this case taking into acount that Ram differences?

Comment: This question can *not* be objectively answered.

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally speaking the speed of the language isn't going to matter much on a web gallery, the thing that is going to take the longest is actually sending the pictures to the client.

But to actually answer your question, ASP.NET will probably run faster, simply because it compiles its code, and unless you are using a PHP accelerator (caching), ASP.NET will probably be faster.

Comment: Altough the RAM with PHP VPS is 4 GB and the RAM with ASP.NET VPS is 2GB?

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you are getting hundreds of requests, or are handling thousands of pictures, the RAM probably won't factor too much into it.